# Are Android / iOS an operating system or a software stack?

Tags: android, ios

I read that Android is not an OS, but a software stack built on the Linux Kernel:
[what is difference between Software Stack and OS ? why Android is not an OS but software stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283725/what-is-difference-between-software-stack-and-os-why-android-is-not-an-os-but)
Is it the same thing with iOS, that it is just a software stack built on Mac OS X?
If iOS is an OS, why is it so?

Comment: Yes, maybe it depends on how big the difference is between iOS and OSX   if iOS should be defined as an OS or just as a software stack based on  OSX? Android is a software stack and not an OS according to most definitions, since it uses the Linux kernel as its OS.

Answer (score 0):

OS X is unix and iOS is a varient of OS X, it has been certified as unix by The Open Group from 10.5 onward: See: [this SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1490) for more information and links. Several years ago changes were made to obtain that status.

Additionally there are frameworks such as CocoaTouch, Foundation, etc. that are part of the development kit. iOS Apps can be developed in any of several languages including Objective-C.